# ACPI BIOS Error: Insufficient arguments

Tags: boot, drivers, system-installation, acpi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. It is keep crashing at different points during the installation. I get the following error message:

```
[0.440324] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): \_SB.PCIO.RP07.PXSX._DSW: Insufficient arguments -ASL declared 1, ACPI requires 3 (20190816/nsarguments-156)
[0.441214] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): \_SB.PCIO.RP09.PXSX._DSW: Insufficient arguments -ASL declared 1, ACPI requires 3 (20190816/nsarguments-156)
[0.496302] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed40fff]
[0.496308] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
[10.907030] nouveau 0000:01:00:0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 022554 [IBUS]
[10.918588] nouveau 0000:01:00:0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 10ac08 [IBUS]
```

I have a HP Pavilion Gaming Notebook with a Insyde F.81 BIOS. I had the same Error when I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTE

Comment: Did you make sure your BIOS is up to date?  Also note that not all BIOS implement *every* component of the ACPI spec properly so this might be specific to your bios/hardware

Comment: Yes, I updated the BIOS to the newest verions F91 and still get the same error